# From Folland Abstract Harmonic Analysis - Why is $\int f(x \xi) d\xi = \int f(x \xi^{-1}) \Delta_H(\xi^{-1}) d \xi$?

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups

From Folland Abstract Harmonic Analysis - Why is $\int f(x \xi) d\xi = \int f(x \xi^{-1}) \Delta_H(\xi^{-1}) d \xi$?

This is on page 57.

Here is the notation:

$H$ is a closed subgroup of a locally compact, Hausdorff group $G$. $d \xi$ is the left Haar measure on $H$. $\Delta_H$ is the modular function.

I know that $\Delta_H(x^{-1}) d \xi$ is the right invariant Haar measure $(d\xi)(E^{-1})$ (or however I should notate that). I am sure that this is part of it, but I can't finish the substitution - I am very bad at calculus, unfortunately. Please help. (Also I'm feeling super lazy right now, but want to get past this point in the book. There, full disclosure.)

Comment: The change of variables that inverts the parameter in the integral converts right/left Haar measure to the other... and left Haar measure is comparable to right Haar measure (or vice-versa) by that expression.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks. That clears it up.